# download multiple images from the server with XMLHttpRequest using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am using the XMLHttpRequest method to get the url of a single image from the server to download, save and then retrieve it from android local storage, and I have succeeded to get it working for a single image url; NOW I AM STUCK on figuring a way to download multiple images from the server using the same method. Can anyone show spare me a way or two ?

Thanks in advance!!!

here the code which I am using to download a single image

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);

        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        console.log(xhr);

        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                console.log(xhr.response);
                // if (success) success(xhr.response);
                saveFile(xhr.response, 'images');
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have list of urls from which images can be downloaded, you can use a simple `for` loop and store `XMLHttpRequest` variable in an array.

```
var xhrList = [];
var urlList = ['example.com/image1',
               'example.com/image2',
               'example.com/image2'];
for (var i=0; i< urlList.length; i++){
    xhrList[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhrList[i].open('GET', urlList[i], true);

    xhrList[i].responseType = "blob";
    console.log(xhrList[i]);

    xhrList[i].onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(this.response);
            // if (success) success(this.response);
            saveFile(this.response, 'images');
        }
    };
    xhrList[i].send();
}
```

Comment: That's really a valuable answer, but what if I have a bigger collection of images in the server? Do I need to put up each and every one of the urls that I wanna use ? @hkbharath

Comment: if you have huge list of images, then add one more request to get the list of URLs from the server. Put all images in same folder, and write a simple server side script to get list list of images in that folder. Send that list to client. !! make sure you start loading images only after you get complete list files !!!

Comment: for now I have only 9 images to be displayed in a same folder, but there will 100s of pics later on. Is there a way that I can take what is inside the  @hkbharath , folder with a url call ? and the other thing is that it bundles all the images in just one file name and couldn't find a way to separate them and save them separately. I tried it like this but still not there yet ' tempString = 'puolukka' + i.toString(); console.log(tempString + ' is this one'); saveFile(this.response, tempString + '.jpg'); '

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask, can you please elaborate more on how the code would look like to list the images in the folder ? thanks  @hkbharath